# Auto Increment in SR# Column using First Name Column and Last Name Column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet which has 2 column.
[image: Please see attached image]

Formula i used in Sr. column (A2) is =IF(B3<>"",IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:A2,MATCH(B3,$B$1:B2,0)),MAX($A$1:A2)+1),"")
This formula gives auto increment in sr column when i put data on client column.

Now i want to edit B1 cell (First Name) and C1 cell (Last Name), how can i use the above formula for getting the previous results. e.g when i fill first name and last name then sr. made auto increment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(B3<>"",IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:A2,MATCH(B3&C3,INDEX($B$1:B2&$C$1:C2,),0)),MAX($A$1:A2)+1),"")
```